# Angular 13 Отправка данных FormData в WebAPI .NET5 приходят пустые данные

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

Заполнение формы

```
submit() {
 const url = CONFIG.api.Users;
 this.usersService
    .addUser(url, this.createData(this.formData), () => {
    })
    .subscribe((user: UserDto) => {
    console.log(user);
    });
}

/**
* Подготовка к передаче в сервис.
* @param formGroup Данные с формы.
* @private
*/
private createData(formGroup: FormGroup) {
 const formValue = formGroup.value;
 let formData = new FormData();

 formData.append(
    "name",
    formValue.userName
 );

 formData.append(
    "email",
    formValue.userEmail
 );

 formData.append(
    "phone",
    formValue.userPhone
 );
 return formData;
}

public addUser(url: string, model: FormData, complete: Function)
 : Observable<UserDto> {
 return this.serverService.post(url, complete, model);
}
```

ServerService

```
post(
 url: string,
 complete: Function,
 body?: Object,
 headers?: HttpHeaders,
 responseType?: any,
 observe?: any
): Observable<any>{
 console.log(`${environment.host}${url}`);
 return this._http
  .post(`${environment.host}${url}`, body, {
    headers: headers || new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      Pragma: 'no-cache',
      Expires: 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT'
    }),
    withCredentials: true,
    observe: observe || 'body',
    responseType: responseType || 'json'
  })
  .pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      complete();
    })
  );
```

.NET

```
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<ActionResult<UserGetDto>> Post([FromForm] UserCreateDto createDto)
  {
      await Task.CompletedTask;
      return Ok(createDto);
  }
```

На сервер приходит пустое ДТО. Не могу понять причину. Может есть простое объянение, но не нашел его.

[image: То что приходит в контроллер]

[image: Данные запроса]

Удаление *'Content-Type'* или замена его на *'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'* не помогает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том что я ожидал на сервере в UserDto int: Phone, а посылал 9876543210 что за границей int.